# Rails FriendlyId and normalize_friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Trying to get my app running the [FriendlyId gem (version 4.0.1)](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

I think I'm doing this in the wrong order, but I want to strip out apostrophes *before* my [friendly_id slug is generated](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged#normalize_friendly_id-instance_method) when creating a new record. But I think the method **normalize_friend_id** is being called after the id is already generated.

I've added the following to my model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  def normalize_friendly_id(string)
    super.gsub("\'", "")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`super` calls the superclass first, meaning the friendly id is being generated then you're running gsub on THAT result. What you really want is to override this method completely.

Refer to: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L244-246

your code should look like this:

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  string.to_s.gsub("\'", "").parameterize
end
```

or

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  super(string.to_s.gsub("\'", ""))
end
```

Hope that helps